# How to set a timeout for a specific port in linux

Tags: linux, tomcat

is there a way to set a timeout for a certain port in linux?

we  have deployed tomcat for a sms banking application and the established connections are not getting closed on port 9010 and they are increasing gradually. so after sometime the system gets hault. when we restart tomcat, all established connections are killed. then again the system works fine.

so is there anyway to kill the established connections setting a timeout for port 9010?

appriciate any help in advance!!

Comment: You should look at how Tomcat handles connections, it is not about Linux.

Comment: thanks for your response. is there solution in tomcat level for this issue. what we have done at the moment is restarting tomcat from a script after certain number of connections are exceeded

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that you're Tomcat is bound to port 9010, you probably have a proxy, such as Apache, in front of Tomcat (if you don't, you really need to consider your architecture before going live).

When configured correctly, proxies will connection pool. By default, Apache will allow a connection for every client up to `Maxclients`, meaning you could easy use up all your Tomcat threads.

The proxy should be configured to only allow n connections though, where n is the number of threads configured in Tomcat.

If the source of the connections are from the same IP address (or small subnet) then you ought to look at the proxy configuration

Comment: actually sms banking module connects to another forwarding module which runs tomcat too. Issue is Established connections between sms banking module and the forwading module are getting increased gradually. is there any solution in tomcat level for this issue? what we have done at the moment is restarting tomcat from a script after certain number of connections are exceeded. and once tomcat is restarted , the system works fine since all the established connections are killed.

Comment: I think you need to review your codebase and infrastructure. You may have connection-pooling enabled within your app but you haven't tuned the thread pools on either service. This could mean any new requests to your SMS app cannot get a free connection from the pool. You may also have a bug in your code which isn't ending connections after fulfilling the client request - This would leave blocked threads and open TCP onward TCP connections.  `maxIdleTime` in Tomcat's Executor is the only attribute which may affect this behaviour. Review your log files and take thread dumps.

Comment: what if i set a session timeout in web.xml in tomcat.does it make sense??

Comment: or what about setting maxkeepalives in http connector? anyway im new to linux.

Comment: Have you looked at the logs and taken thread dumps as I've suggested?

Comment: ERROR - ThreadedTelcoSender:run() [Thread-581]  sms ID : [1491204906652]Error in
 the sending thread bank to telco ID: 8
java.lang.Exception: Forwarding Server Not Available  or Telco Server Not Availa

Comment: I took several thread dumps with the increase of ESTABLISHED connections. I will attach you here some ERRORS that was printed

Comment: ERROR - HttpClient:sendRequestToTelco() : [Thread-720] Error sending msg to forwarding module (bank-->forwarding)

Comment: i just took a full thread dump and there are many threads for http 9010. i will do a reserach and get to you if i need to know anything

Comment: i took full thread dumps and investigated. and it seems threads are not dying. and the number of threads is increasing. my supervisor ask me to reduce the session time out in web.xml does it make sense?

Comment: Does your supervisor know what the OSI model is?